# Unable to call function in button in jsx code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webapi

I have a functional component like the following. Because of the use of some Web API, I have to render some HTML elements within the function `infoWindow.setContent()`. When I tried to bind the button with `onclick` function, it does not return anything. Does anyone know why?

```
const Map = () => {
...
  useEffect(() => {
    const infoWindow = new AMap.InfoWindow({})
    const sayHello = () => {
      console.log("hello")
    }
    infoWindow.setContent("<p>Hello</p><button type='submit' onclick='${sayHello}'>Say Hello</button>"
  }
}
```

In the above scenario, I want to return hello in console.log, but it appears that no such message can be found when I click on the button.

Comment: You are passing a string literal where the button callback is `'${sayHello}'`. Perhaps you meant to use a template literal?

Answer (score 1):

Changing DOM in that way is not considered good practice in React.js. But if you don't have any other options, I think you can try this way;

```js
const Map = () => {
...
  const sayHello = () => {
    console.log("hello")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const infoWindow = new AMap.InfoWindow({})
    const element = <p>Hello</p><button type='submit' onClick={sayHello}>Say Hello</button>

    infoWindow.setContent(element)
  });
}
```